# Disable lagging scrollbar in Chrome Developer Tools sources window

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbar, google-chrome-devtools

After a recent update to Google Chrome (currently I'm at 30.0.1599.101), the Sources window of the Developer Tools now has the scrollbar lag as I drag it down. The effect is kind of like Facebook's 'infinite scroll', in that if I drag the scrollbar to the bottom, it doesn't actually scroll to the very end of the source. Instead goes only part of the way, and the scrollbar position then pops back up toward the middle. In order to get to the end or even middle of a longer document, I have to drag the scrollbar down multiple times. The only workaround I see is to hit Ctrl-End (Windows) and then scroll back upwards, which seems like unnecessary extra keystrokes.

This lag effect is appropriate for applications like Facebook, but it's very irritating here. Is there any way to disable this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=269941 that is fixed in M31. You could wait for it to reach stable or try using dev/beta/canary channel as a workaround for now.